# How to use WebDriverWait in an if statement for multiple elements efficiently?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, webdriverwait

Assuming that I have 3 different scenarios in those different scenarios different elements are shown.

How can I use `WebDriverWait` for multiple elements and if one of those elements are found ignore the finding of other elements.

I had tried `WebDriverWait` to sleep for `x` number of seconds then do an if statement with `driver.find_element_by_id` and find if the elements are present but this is highly inefficient because the page can take longer/less to load, you can see what I tried in the following code:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
if len(driver.find_elements_by_id('something1')) > 0:
    *do something*
elif len(driver.find_element_by_id('something2')) > 0:
    *do something*
elif len(driver.find_element_by_id('something3')) > 0:
    *do something*
```

I also tried  `WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'something')))` with a `try` and `except` but this is the most inefficient method as it because it takes much more longer longer.

Comment: assuming you are ranking them in order of importance from top to bottom, can't you just add a `break`statement  under each `*do something*`? Actually it doesn't need to be in order of importance if all you care about is if ANY element is found.  Either way though, I think `break` should work for this use case

Comment: @JD2775 Def not the solution for me, since i have to wait for the page to be loaded first with webdriverwait or through a sleep if not it would raise an error, also break will not work because it is gonna have different code based on the element found.

Comment: well you'd need to adjust your `find element by` to include the wait method wrapped around it.  You already have the `WebDriverWait(driver, 30)` initiated above the `if` block, just change how you are finding the elements below it to incorporate it.  Also, not sure how the "different code based on the element found" matters, the break is going beneath that, in each if/else statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to wait until one of three elements is presented you can use the following `ExpectedConditions` example since
`ExpectedConditions` supports multiple arguments.
So you can use something like the following:

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "first_element_id, second_element_id, third_element_id"))
```

Now, if you need to know what element is present and what not, the simplest way to do that is using the `driver.find_elements`

```
is_first_element_present = driver.find_elements_by_id(first_element_id)
is_second_element_present = driver.find_elements_by_id(second_element_id)
is_third_element_present = driver.find_elements_by_id(third_element_id)
```

Now, each of those elements is a list. In case the element is present, the list is not empty and in case the element is absent the list is empty.
And since non-empty list is Boolean `True` in Python and empty list is `False` you can use it directly with `if` case:

```
if(is_first_element_present):
   do_something
elif(is_second_element_present):
   do_that
   -----
etc
```

Comment: This is a great answer but not a viable solution for me, i need to know what element has been found since it can be any element of the 3. Also it wont cause an exception timeout if 1 or 2 elements are not found?

Comment: This is a better solution that i had in mind but im struggling with the part that i dont want to run the if statements if the page is not loaded and i dont want to do a sleep before the statements because it can take longer/less for the page to load. In my mind i was thinking if statements with your first solution but that will wait much longer in an if elif statement. At the end ill just do with sleep this is too much of an headache.

Comment: These are opposite scenarios. If you just want to wait for 1 of several elements to appear (and this is what you asked as far as I understood) - use the solution I provided. In case you want to validate the final state of ALL the 3 elements I see no way, only to use a dedicated `ExpectedConditions` for each element that will return `True` or `False`, `True` if element is found and `False` when the timeout reached. So, in this case you will wait at least for the entire single timeout period defined within your `WebdriverWait`.